# Php vars within javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a bit of code to record a certain action

```
$('#record').click(function(){
$.get("../confirm.php", { "id": '<?php echo $record; ?>' }, function(data){});
});
```

Which works fine, but i don't want the page to be full of javascript and such as i have other things like this on it too, so i am trying to move it to a js file.

In the php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">var record = "<?= $record ?>";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsfile.js"></script>
```

In the js file

```
$('#record').click(function(){
$.get("../confirm.php", { id: record}, function(data){});
});
```

But it doesnt want to play ball, any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Don't use the `<?=` syntax to output code. It being the only difference I can see...I'd say that's also the problem with your code. Check the JS Console of your browser for any errors.

Comment: can't you wrap it all in functions and use onclick events on the actual buttons so you can pass variables in via the onclick

Comment: what gets output in browser source for `var record`?

Comment: I dont normally use ?>= syntax but i viewed the source and it outputs ok, $record is set as get id further up in the page

Comment: need to inspect request in browser and provide more details than `won't play ball`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I may a suggestion to you. Set in the view on the element the ID. Then when the action is clicked, get the id for the data.

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="inputName" id="<?php echo $record; ?>" class="btnToRecord" />

$('.btnToRecord').click(function(){
    var clickedElement = $(this);
    $.get("../confirm.php", { id: clickedElement.attr("id") }, function(data){});
});
```

Edit: Correction for $(this) was pointing to the get instead to the element, putting in a var will fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Make 'record' as class of div and assign php variable $record as its id.Use event.target.id to get variable $record  from div.

```
<div class="record" id="<?php echo $record;?>">
 Your code here
</div>
```

And Use this
    $('.record').click(function(event){
    var record=event.target.id;
    //your code here
    });